# How to use biber with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: texlive, biber, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, TexLive 2012 from backports, TexLive full installation.

However, when I try to compile via latexmk, I get an error message that biber is missing.

How to get biber working on 12.04 - but please only with packages from the repository, not with manual installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have no Ubuntu installed so I couldn't try it, but I found the following link to a package http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/quantal/biber. Maybe this helps you, otherwise there is the possibility to install it manually (also you mentioned you don't want to) by getting binaries from [http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber).

The third option is to not use Ubuntu's TeX Live but the plain one from [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive). With this I got biber installed per default in a full installation on my Arch Linux machine.

Comment: Well, the above mentioned packages are for 12.10, codenamed Quantal. Seems I have to go for the manual install, despite I don't want to...

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong version of Ubuntu. I got confused by all these names… Is there a way to backport this package? I don't know, if you can do this with Ubuntu…

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which part in the process is causing the problem. (The most likely cause should be not installing `biber`.)

Anyway, I
will try to give a complete rundown of the process. This is supposed to be
a comprehensive answer which should benefit future visitors.

---

**Software/Packages**

First of all, make it sure that we have all the necessary packages installed.

***`pdflatex`***

In a terminal (press Ctrl-Alt-t to get one) execute,

```
apt-cache search pdflatex
```

You get something like,

> ```
> texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
> texlive-latex-recommended - TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
> ```

Execute,

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended
```

***`biber`***

Execute,

```
apt-cache search biber
```

You get something like,

> biber - Much-augmented BibTeX replacement for BibLaTeX users

Execute,

```
sudo apt-get install biber
```

***`biblatex`***

Execute,

```
apt-cache search biblatex
```

You get something like,

> texlive-bibtex-extra - TeX Live: BibTeX additional styles

Execute,

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra
```

***`latexmk`***

Execute,

```
apt-cache search latexmk
```

You get something like,

> latexmk - Perl script for running LaTeX the correct number of times

Execute,

```
sudo apt-get install latexmk
```

Now, your software/package installation part should be complete.

---

**Actual Compilation**

As our test source files, let us say that we have two files.

`biberusage.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, defernumbers=true, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biberusage.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing the paper~\cite{entrykey}.

\end{document}
```

`biberusage.bib`

```
@Article{entrykey,
  author =   {Author One and Author Two and Author Three},
  title =    {Paper Title},
  journal =      {Journal Name},
  year =     {2016},
  OPTkey =   {},
  OPTvolume =    {},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  OPTpages =     {},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}
```

Now, let us try individual compilation first (my preferred way of doing anything).

Execute,

```
pdflatex biberusage.tex
biber biberusage
pdflatex biberusage.tex
pdflatex biberusage.tex
```

Please note that in the second step, you should use the name of 
`biberusage.tex` without the `.tex` extension. 
The name `biberusage.bib` has nothing to do here.

Or we can try using latexmk.

Execute,

```
latexmk -pdf biberusage.tex
```

Everything should work nice and easy.